# Confusion Matrix on H2O

Tags: python, random-forest, h2o, confusion-matrix

**Final Edit:** this problem ended up occurring because the target array were integers that were supposed to represent categories so it was doing a regression. Once I converted them into factors using `.asfactor()`, then the confusion matrix method detailed in the answer below worked

---

I am trying to run a confusion matrix on my Random Forest Model (`my_model`), but the documentation has been less than helpful. From [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o-tutorials/latest-stable/H2OTutorialsBook.pdf) it says the command is `h2o.confusionMatrix(my_model)` but there is no such thing in 3.0.

Here are the steps to fit the model:

```
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator

data_h = h2o.H2OFrame(data)
train, valid = data_h.split_frame(ratios=[.7], seed = 1234)

my_model = H2ORandomForestEstimator(model_id = "rf_h", ntrees = 400, 
max_depth = 30, nfolds = 8, seed = 25)
my_model.train(x = features, y = target, training_frame=train)
pred = rf_h.predict(valid)
```

I have tried the following:

```
my_model.confusion_matrix()

AttributeError: type object 'H2ORandomForestEstimator' has no attribute 
'confusion_matrix'
```

Gotten from [this example](http://blog.cypresspoint.com/2017/10/19/H2O-classification-random-forest-grid-search.html).

I have attempted to use tab completion to find out what it might be and have tried:

```
h2o.model.confusion_matrix(my_model)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

and

```
h2o.model.ConfusionMatrix(my_model)
```

which outputs simply all the model diagnostics and then the error:

```
H2OTypeError: Argument `cm` should be a list, got H2ORandomForestEstimator
```

Finally,

```
h2o.model.ConfusionMatrix(pred)
```

Which gives the same error as above.

Not sure what to do here, how can I view the results of the confusion matrix of the model?

Edit: Added more code to the beginning of the question for Context

Comment: are you doing a regression or classification problem? I was not able to reproduce this issue for a classification problem.

Comment: @Lauren Hi, I included more context in the top of the code block. I realize that I did not run any predictions on the validation set so I tried running `h2o.model.ConfusionMatrix(pred)` which did not work. This is a classification problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?highlight=confusion_matrix#h2o.model.binomial.H2OBinomialModel.confusion_matrix) for the full parameter list. For your convenience here is the list `confusion_matrix(metrics=None, thresholds=None, train=False, valid=False, xval=False)`.

Here is a working example of how to use the method:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
h2o.init()


# import the cars dataset:
# this dataset is used to classify whether or not a car is economical based on
# the car's displacement, power, weight, and acceleration, and the year it was made
cars = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/junit/cars_20mpg.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
cars["economy_20mpg"] = cars["economy_20mpg"].asfactor()

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors = ["displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year"]
response = "economy_20mpg"

# split into train and validation sets
train, valid = cars.split_frame(ratios = [.8], seed = 1234)

# try using the binomial_double_trees (boolean parameter):
# Initialize and train a DRF
cars_drf = H2ORandomForestEstimator(binomial_double_trees = False, seed = 1234)
cars_drf.train(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid)
cars_drf.confusion_matrix()
# or specify the validation frame
cars_drf.confusion_matrix(valid=True)
```